# maven multiple project dependency issue

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have two maven projects in my eclipse. Say `employee` and `address`. My intention is to add the `address.jar` as a dependency to my `employee.jar` since employee project needs the classes inside address. I understand that just declaring the address as a dependency in `employee's pom.xml` is not sufficient. I ran `eclipse:eclipse` command on employee so that `address.jar` is mentioned in the employee project's `.classpath` file.

After running the above command, when I opened the `.classpath` file of employee I saw something like this --> let me call it **A**

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="/address"/>
```

Now, when I closed the `address` project in my eclipse. I got the following error.

> Project 'employee' is missing required Java project: 'address'
>
> The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved

But whereas, I was expecting something like this in the employee `.classpath` file.  --> let me call this B

```
<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/trial/1.0/address-1.0.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/com/trial/1.0/address-1.0-sources.jar"/>
```

***P.S:*** when I replaced **A** with **B**, the error disappeared.

**Questions:**

1. What is the difference between **A** and **B**?
2. Why did I not see an entry like **B** in the employee's `.classpath` file?
3. Why am I getting the above-mentioned error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven works with artifacts installed in a Maven repository.  This can either be your local repository in `.m2/repository` or a repository manager like Nexus or Artifactory.

A jar file in your file system does not qualify.  You must install it.  See [how to download and install jar in my local repo Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12873586/53897)

After you have installed it, you can declare it as a `<dependency>` in your pom.xml file as needed.

Comment: Also you should not use `eclipse:eclipse` anymore.  The m2e plugin in Eclipse give much better support for Maven projects.

Comment: I am using m2e plugin in eclipse. I ran `eclipse:eclipse` in goals field of eclipse's Run Configuration window.

I referred (http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-add-a-project-as-a-dependency-of-another-project.html?page=1) tutorial.

Comment: Do not run `eclipse:eclipse` when using m2e.

Comment: Oh ok. then how do I make the dependencies I entered in my `pom.xml ` to reflect in my .classpath file?

Comment: This is what m2e should do for you almost automatically when you change your pom.xml.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already installed the jar as a result of which the jar could be seen in my local maven repository. Can you please answer the 3 questions as I find them very confusing?